# Integrating with PayPal with no web site

Tags: rest, paypal, desktop-application

I was thinking about integration in the background without any website other than the payment page as part of a desktop application in c++. 
Would it be possible to following the following scenario:
1. Generate the invoice / sale and via REST API obtain some sort of unique ID for the transaction to come.
2. Redirect to Paypal web site to a ad-hoc payment page, using the unique ID.
3. In the background, check every few minutes, via REST API, if the payment was made.

Answer (score 1):

We finally found a way, which is why I publish this answer along with some code (a POC) we have developed. This is a POC for a built-in payment processing engine which allows you to accept payments from any credit card holder (regardless of being a PayPal customer) and pay for unlocking a software product or for specific features.

To process payments you need to apply as a [PayPal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/) and obtain your own PayPal credentials. You will then receive 2 sets of credentials. One for tests ("sandbox") and the other for real life.

First you can use the Sandbox to test the API

```
Void InitPayPal(BOOL Sandbox, LPTSTR User, LPTSTR password, LPTSTR signature, LPTSTR successUrl, LPTSTR failedURL)
```

**Sandbox** – indicates whether you are testing your integration using PayPal's Sandbox account, or going live.

**User** – your PayPal user name

**Password** – your PayPal password

**Signature** – you PayPal signature

**successUrl** – a url leading to a web page which you wish to be shown after successful payment.

**failedURL** – a url leading to a web page which you wish to be shown after failed / cancalled payment.

This function is straight forward:

```
void InitPayPal(BOOL Sandbox, LPTSTR User, LPTSTR password, LPTSTR signature, LPTSTR successUrl, LPTSTR failedURL, LPWSTR ProductName)
{
    m_sandbox = Sandbox;
    m_user = User;
    m_password = password;
    m_signature = signature;
    m_SuccessURL = successUrl;
    m_FailureURL = failedURL;
    m_ProductName = ProductName;
    CUR_CHAR = L"$";
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    GetSystemTime(&st);
    g_tPayStart = CTime(st);
    InitilizedPaypal = TRUE;
}
```

**Initiating a payment**
When you wish to initiate a payment from your program, you call the following function which I wrote which generally build a string (ExpChkoutStr) and use the following PayPal API call:

```
// Send string to PayPal server
WinHttpClient WinClient1(ExpChkoutStr.GetBuffer());
WinClient1.SetRequireValidSslCertificates(false);
WinClient1.SendHttpRequest(L"GET");
httpResponseContent1 = WinClient1.GetResponseContent();
CString strTransactionRet = UrlDecode(httpResponseContent1.c_str());
```

*The [WinHTTP class](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C) was developed by [Cheng Shi](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=2293307).*

The Express Checkout String (ExpChkoutStr) is generated by another function which uses the member variables' values and the transaction details into a single string:

```
CString result;
result = (m_sandbox) ? PAYPAL_SANDBOX_HTTPS : PAYPAL_REAL_HTTPS;
result += Q_USER;
result += m_user;
result += AND_PASSWORD;
result += m_password;
result += AND_SIGNATURE;
result += m_signature;
result += AND_PAYMENTAMOUNT;
result += strAmount;
result += L"&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout";
result += AND_RETURN_URL;
result += m_SuccessURL;
result += AND_CANCEL_URL;
result += m_FailureURL;
result += AND_VERSION;
result += L"&NOSHIPPING=1";
result += L"&ADDROVERRIDE=0&BRANDNAME=Secured Globe, Inc.";
result += L"&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=";
result += L"Item name: " + strUnits + L"(" + UnitName + L") ";
result += L"Price: " + strAmount;
result += L"&NOTETOBUYER=Here you can add a note to the buyer";
```

The result from the PayPal server is a "token" used to figure out a one-time web page (LinkToOpen ) that must be opened in order for the end user to confirm the purchase:

```
// Extract token from response
CString sToken = ExtractElement(strTransactionRet, L"TOKEN");

if (sToken == L"")
{
    wprintf(L"Internal error: (Paypal): no token was generated (%s)", strTransactionRet);
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Internal payment processing error", L"", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}
CString LinkToOpen = (m_sandbox) ? SANDBOX_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT : REAL_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT;

LinkToOpen += L"&token=";
LinkToOpen += sToken;
```

We then programatically open this one-time web page using the default web browser:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CString command_line;
command_line.Format(L"cmd.exe /c start \"link\" \"%s\" ", LinkToOpen);
// LinkToOpen
if (!CreateProcess(NULL,     // No module name (use command line)
    command_line.GetBuffer(),
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inhberitable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    wprintf(L"CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
// At this stage you would want to mark this transaction as "failed"
    return FALSE;
}
```

Then the rest is to maintain a small database of all pending transactions and follow up each of them until it is either succeed, failed, cancelled or if a timeout has passed.

To extract elements from the PayPal server response, we wrote this small function:

```
CString ExtractElement(CString EntireString, CString ElementName)
{
    CString result = L"";
    CString WhatToFind = ElementName + L"=";
    int foundToken = EntireString.Find(WhatToFind);
    if (foundToken > -1)
    {
        int EndToken = EntireString.Find(L"&", foundToken);
        if (EndToken != -1)
        {
            result = EntireString.Mid(foundToken + ElementName.GetLength()+1, EndToken - foundToken - ElementName.GetLength()-1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```